# Copy value of the cell to a new column if it has a specific keyword

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 1 column with 600 entries where I need to move, to a new column, only those entries which has a keyword "test" in them, but not exact match. Looking for a Google Sheets formula, Excel works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your column is A, try

```
=query(A:A,"where A like '%test%' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=FILTER(A:A; A:A="test")
```